# Rails caching not working on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, I have used caching. This is the code, I have used. In after_filter, I called the method which include this one line code.

```
Rails.cache.write("properties", @properties.to_xml)
```

I try to get this in another action in before_filter like

```
@hotels = Rails.cache.fetch("properties")
```

this all working fine in development machine. But in server it returns null value. the application run in same development mode in server. Can you please anyone suggest me the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What server are you running? What backend is Rails' cache setup to use?

Comment: nginx+phusion passenger.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't configured a backend for the store, so it will use [ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html)

From the documentation:

> If you're running multiple Ruby on Rails server processes (which is the case if you're using mongrel_cluster or Phusion Passenger), then this means that Rails server process instances won't be able to share cache data with each other.

This works in development since you are likely using a single server instance, so the cache is only stored in one process. For production you need to configure an alternative shared store. I'd recommend running a memcached instance, and installing and using the [Dalli Gem](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) as per the [README](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/README.md).